# How to get contents of curl uploaded file in django

Tags: django, file, curl, upload

I'm using Django 2.1.1 and would like to upload a file using this curl command:

```
curl -i  -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e https://neon/accounts/login/ \
--cert client.crt --key client.key -F  "name=@afile" \
-H "X-CSRFToken: 9rQMPHGdPJHLVbSEmhwXLc1m9i1KIQVVenRPqP2JkqrldKgWX4GMahOET7pk5cnw" \
-H "Content-type: multipart/form-data" \
-X POST -F 'test=blaat' https://neon/test/
```

the url goes to the following view:

```
def test(request):
    response = pprint.pformat(request.FILES, indent=4)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

The result of curl is:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018 14:37:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 72
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{   'name': <InMemoryUploadedFile: afile (application/octet-stream)>}
```

So how can I get the contents of 'afile' in a str variable in Django... I tried request.FILES['file'].chunks() but don't really have an idea of what I am trying here. Also writing the contents to a file on the server: no idea. The main thing is to get it into a variable so I can for example parse JSON from that file.

The login, SSL certificates and authentication all works fine. That's not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `read` function on the file, and then decode using the appropriate encoding:

```
from io import BytesIO

data = request.FILES['name'].read()
data = data.decode('utf-8')
```